# ¿Cómo llamar la última entrada ingresada al wordpress desde el menú?

Tags: wordpress

Quisiera que al seleccionar una opción específica del menú, me muestre la última entrada ingresada en el CMS wordpress.
¿Es posible?

Answer (score 1):

Recomiendo hacer una en Wordpress una pagina llamada "lastpost" y hacer una en la plantilla un archivo llamado page-lastpost.php con el siguiente contenido:

```
get_header(); ?>

    <?php query_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    )); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            // Include the page content template.
            get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        ?>

        </main><!-- .site-main -->
    </div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

y por último pones en el menu la pagina llamada "lastpost".